# jQuery: Deleting specific li/ appending button to appended li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a button that would delete a specific list item. I tried this but it obvioulsy deletes all li.

```
$('button').click(() => {
let todos = $('input').val();
$('ul').append(
    '<li id="one">'+todos+'</li>',
     '<button class="delete" id="kosz"></button>'
     );
     $('button.delete').button({
        icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
    },
        text: false,
    });
    $('button.delete').css('background', 'none');
    $('button.delete').click(() => {
       $('#one').remove(''),
     })
})
```

I searched the answers and tried to use $(this), but li is not a parent element to button, so it doesn't work.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'button.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove('');
  $(this).remove('');
});
```

I tried making the button a parent element to the li, and then it works but also new buttons are created with every click.

```
$('button').click(() => {
let todos = $('input').val();
$('ul').append(
    '<li id="one">'+todos+'</li>',
     $('li').append(
        '<button class="delete" id="kosz"></button>'
     )
     );
     $('button.delete').button({
        icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
    },
        text: false,
    });
})
```

I am absolutely new to it, I understand why it doesn't work and that I should make a function that appends button to li outside that on click function, but nothing I tried works. The answers I found are using some advanced stuff and they are not applicable to my code.

Please, provide me some guidelines.

EDIT: Adding HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <title>ToDo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>To do:</h1>
        <ul></ul>
        <div class="tasks">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter todo...">
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src=./scripts.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML as well so we can see the DOM structure

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap a `div` for you `li` and `button` and then use the `closest` method to remove the wrapping div.

Also, you shouldn't hard-code `id`s into elements that you're creating dynamically, try using an iterator or an index to append a value to your `id` field.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  let todos = $('input').val();
  const elem = `
    <div class="todo-item">
      <li class="list-item">${todos}</li>
      <button class="delete"></button>
    </div>
  `
  $('ul').append(elem);
  $('button.delete').button({
    icons: {
      primary: 'ui-icon-trash'
    },
    text: false,
  });
  $('ul').on('click', 'button.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('.todo-item').remove();
  })
});
```

```css
.todo-item {
  display: flex;
}

.delete {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>To do:</h1>
    <ul></ul>
    <div class="tasks">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter todo...">
      <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```